# MVC form post not reaching controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form that on submit doesn't reach the controller method (I put a breakpoint there)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveBilling( FormCollection fc )
    {
...
}
```

the frontend code is something like this

```
<form action="/PersonSettings/SaveBilling" method="post" >
...
<input type='submit' value="save" />
</form>
```

any ideas ?

not sure if it is a route handler problem because it does reach the GET version if i go to /PersonSettings/SaveBilling in browser but the post method just yields a blank page and doesnt go into the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a routing related issue after all , I have some complex routes and the default mvc route was catching things that should have gone through the default mvc route with areas.

Was able to recreate the issue by having explicit parameters for my function instead of a formcollection, so that might have been the issue ohwell.

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite your view as:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveBilling", "PersonSettings", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ....
    <input type='submit' value="save" />
}
```

Is this controller in any area or not?

Comment: for some reason the helper functions render an incorrect url in my current solution, I have areas but not using areas for this view/action

Comment: "helper functions render an incorrect url" that cause problem with routing your post to controller.

Comment: I have other forms that work in the same project. There I don't use helper functions just the form tags manually as above.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this has been solved, but I thought I'd tack on another possible cause: Having the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute on your method without an `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your code will create the same problem.

Comment: Thanks bro, keep answering questions even if it is solved .

Answer (score 0):

use form and define action path.

```
<form id="subscriptionForm" action="/Category/Create" method="post"> 

--your div 

</form >
```

Now use script to serialize the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#Save').click(function () {
            var form = $("#subscriptionForm");
            var url = form.attr("action");
            var formData = form.serialize();
            $.post(url, formData, function (data) {
                $("#msg").html(data);
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Now you can reach your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using a network sniffing tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is helpful to see what's wrong when the request is sent and it seems not reaching the server.